# CSS Filter (any) hiding elements after a checkbox is absolute positioned in Chrome 62

Tags: css-filters

Below are some images of the form which I want to show a dialogue over, and want to blur the background. This works fine on other browsers but in Chrome Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit) It is creating problems

Here is the layout and the checkbox, 
[image]

Its a toggle button to change size input fields

[image]

Here is the css for the checkbox

`opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -999999999px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;`

After applying the blur filter my form is emptied. 
[image]

Just writing here for the question, I found that the `margin-top: -99999999px` is quite a big number and when I changed it to `margin-top: -999999px` it worked.

I was about to ask why my elements are not visible on the page, but as I already have fix it, I want to know the reason for it and to put this question here for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was with a checkbox positioned absolute and having very high negative margin top. Lowered the number and it is fixed.